# What's the best way to store settings on a per-worksheet basis?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to temporarily store my macro's settings for each worksheet. I thought about extending the active sheet's properties to store the settings there. The goal would be to read a property such as ActiveSheet.Setting1. I've tried wrapping the ActiveSheet object in a class:

"cCustomSheet" class module:

```
Public WithEvents WS As Worksheet
Public Setting1 As String
```

"Module1" module:

```
Dim ActiveWS As cCustomSheet
Sub test1()
    Set ActiveWS = New cCustomSheet
    Set ActiveWS.WS = ActiveSheet
End Sub
Sub test2()
    MsgBox ActiveWS.WS.Name
End Sub
```

This code works without an error, but `ActiveWS` should be updated to the new active sheet if the user activates another sheet, and it's not. If I remove the `Set` keyword from the line `Set ActiveWS.WS = ActiveSheet`, I get the following error:

> Error n° 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

How should I do it, and is this even possible?

I also thought about using ActiveSheet.CustomProperties but this seems rather clumsy since you can't retrieve a setting by its name (without looping through all of the items), and you have to rely on index numbers.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: I should add that my macro will be stored as an Excel Add-in, therefore I won't have access to the code of the workbooks of the users. I cannot take advantage of the Worksheet_Activate() event to keep track of the active sheet. Also, the settings would preferably be lost or reset to their default values when the workbook is reopened, that's why I can't save them inside the user's file (in a hidden sheet for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. They have helped me finding a way to store my settings for each worksheet. I've used `ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties` to assign a random ID to the active workbook. Each worksheet is identified by the concatenation of the workbook's ID and the sheet's codename (which is unique inside a workbook). The settings for the active worksheet are added to a collection where the sheet's ID serves as the index, so that they can be retrieved easily.

This is not 100% safe since two workbooks can hypothetically get the same ID, since it's a random number. The workbook's ID is also saved to the Excel file. It becomes useless after the workbook is closed but "pollutes" the custom properties list of the file.

I also needed to store the address of the column holding the values on which to apply my macro. This is set by the user. Instead of storing the absolute address of the range, I'm using the .ID property of the first cell of the column. This way, if the user moves the cells, the ID sticks to the values. The downside is that I have to cycle through every cell of the first row of the selection to check if a cell holds an .ID value, which is quite inelegant. The .ID property is gone after the workbook is reopened, which is fine for me because I didn't want the settings to be persistent.

Answer (score 4):

To get you at least part way there:

In Module1 just have the line:

```
Public ActiveWS As cCustomSheet
```

Notice that it's now declared as Public.

In the ThisWorkbook module try this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Set ActiveWS = New cCustomSheet
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Set ActiveWS.WS = ActiveSheet
With ActiveWS
     Debug.Print .WS.Name
    .Setting1 = "something important about this sheet"
End With
End Sub
```

The thing to note is you'll lose whatever is in Setting1 for one sheet once you activate the next, but if you just want to access the properties while the sheet is active, this should do it. If not, you can add all the sheets to a Collection or Dictionary, which will keep the properties for all of them accessible as long as the Collection or Dictionary exists.  So... let us know a little more about your goals here and I'll try to help you think through the best option.

EDIT: In a more general answer to your question, I tend to store settings in worksheet names, which can be completely hidden from users if desired.  This could be a good way to go especially if you need the settings to persist between times that the workbook is opened.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. However, my macro is stored in an Excel Add-In, which means that it will be used on other Workbooks. I can't touch the code of the workbook on which it will be used. Also, the users will probably work on several sheets at once, which means that my macro will have to keep its settings for each of the sheets simultaneously. If I keep the sheets in a collection, how to keep track of which is which? I will probably have to rely on index numbers or sheet names, which I didn't want to in the first place. For example, if a sheet gets renamed, it should keep its settings.

Comment: The answer to keeping track is to use the sheets' codenames, at least assuming that you created, or have access to the original versions of, the workbooks on which they'll be working.  Happily, I just wrote a post on this on my brand-new blog at: http://yoursumbuddy.com/using-worksheet-codenames-in-other-workbooks/.  Also, if you look at the very first post there's an example of adding listobjects to a collection, a little different, but it might help.  These are all soluble issues so far.

Comment: I should also add that I'd prefer if the settings were not persistent. A user might save his workbook and send it to someone else, and my macro would behave with the previous user's preferences, which could be confusing.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this issue. Sheet's codenames are only unique inside a given workbook. Once I open two workbooks, I will also have to keep track of the workbook's names to identify each open sheet uniquely. But if the workbooks' name changes (as it is the case when the user saves a new workbook), my settings would be lost because I could not retrieve them using the new workbook's name. I'd rather avoid saving the settings in a hidden sheet in the user's workbook, because I would prefer if the settings were reset after re-opening the workbook.

Comment: It sounds like your addin needs an application-level event class that checks every workbook that opens for an identifier, typically a Name or CustomDocumentProperty. When it identifies a "Target" workbook it should add it to a collection of workbooks, also defined in a class, inside which you need to handle your processing, so that it happens automatically for any workbook that's in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project where I needed to send out sheets with settings but the macros were in my master sheet, not the distributed sheets.

I found storing the settings in a named range worked very well.  You can store any string, number or formula and you can even use the values in the sheet if required.

Answer (score 0):

As your macro is in an Excel Addin, you could store the information in the sheets of that addin, which are not visible. You can even make that sheet "very hidden" if you want to make sure nobody unhides it by mistake.
For example, you could name the Sheet1 of your addin "Parameters" and store on each line, the workbook name in column A and the parameter in column B.

By the way, this makes sure that the data is not lost if an error in the code causes all the variables to be reset.

Alternatively, if you need that setting to be available after closing and reopening Excel, which does not seem to be the case, you could create a very hidden sheet in the workbook and store your data there, but that requires changing that workbook.